# Html read application cache to retrieve the version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-cache

We all experience issues with offline caching mechanisme.
I would like to be able to print the version off the application cache.

This number is put in the manifest itself in the second line like this :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v19
...
```

I tried to use to read the file using jquery :

```
 <script>
    function showVersion()
    {
        $.get("main.appcache", function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

But I have got a 404 : not found.

Anyone tried to do this before?

Comment: Oups, I renamed the cache file for not having caching during development.

Answer (score 0):

It is finaly working, the piece of code :

```
    <script>
    function showVersion()
    {
        $.get("main.appcache", function(data) {
            var lines = data.split("\n");
            alert(lines[1].substring(1));
        });
    }
    </script>

...

<a href="#/" onclick="showVersion()">Version</a>
```

With `main.appcache` :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v21
....
```

Working example : [splitons](http://splitons.com)